# Gitlab pipeline fails to run msbuild for UWP project but works fine locally

Tags: msbuild, gitlab-ci

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the repository of my C#/UWP project which requires a gitlab runner with shell to run. I am having problems simply building the project, the job can be seen here:

```
variables:
MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
VSTEST_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'

stages:
  - build
  - test

build-job:
  only:
  - web
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building..."
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" -restore /p:Platform=x64'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - <project1>\bin
      - <project2>\bin
      - <project3>\bin
      - <project4>\bin
      - <project5>\bin
      - <project6>\bin
      - <project7>\bin

test-job1:
etc....
```

So basically this command `- '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" -restore /p:Platform=x64'` runs perfectly fine in powershell and cmd on the machine that has the gitlab runner installed. But as soon as i manually kick off this pipeline it gives me a tone of `CSC : error CS0006` with no other indication and i simply dont understand why (this project builds and runs fine in visual studio).

From gitlab job view i can see about 150 of these errors,

[image: CSC : error CS0006 errors]

But again, running this command locally on the same machine with the same gitlab runner build directory works just fine.

**What have I tried so far:**

1. Rebooting the machine running the gitlab runner.
2. Restarting the gitlab runner service.
3. Different combinations of parameters to msbuild but it always fails while never failing locally.
4. Deleting the gitlab runners repo directory, it make a new one and fails the same way again.
5. Manually going into the gitlab runner repo directory with the project in it and calling the exact same command as in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, works fine: 
   [image: Working in powershell]

I am out of ideas as to what the issue could be. Really hope someone can help.

Comment: Could be an account problem where the runner runs as the SYSTEM account or similar with a different environment. Configure the service to run as your local user account? And/or change the build to first run vsdevcmd.bat as that would make sure all environment variables are correctly set?

Answer (score 1):

As `stijn` has mentioned and after more careful analysis between the pipeline and the local build it turns out the issue was because the gitlab runner runs on some sort of "system" profile while i was logged in as a specific user on the machine.

For what ever reason, running the msbuild x86 from the system profile makes the NuGet part never run which is why i get all those `CSC : error CS0006` errors. The solution was very simple. Inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` i changed

```
MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
to
MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe'
```

in order to run the x64 version of msbuild and this solves my issue.